# Unable to fetch images from mongoDB on a cyclic deployed website

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, web-hosting

I am trying to fetch images stored on mongoDB atlas, they are stored in buffer format, when i fetch them on my local machine they work fine, but i have deployed the webapp on cyclic, and when i fetch images it gives error 404, although all other information stored in that mongoDb collection is fetched with no problem.

Working URL (Localhost): http://localhost:3000/question-images/A%2043-year-old%20man%20comes%20to%20the%20physician%20for%20a%20follow-up%20examination.%20Ten%20years%20ago%2C%20he%20underwent%20cardiac%20valve%20replacement.%20Chest%20x-rays%20are%20shown.%20Based%20on%20these%20findings%2C%20which%20of%20the%20following%20valves%20was%20most%20likely%20replaced%20in%20this%20patient%3F

Not Working URL (Cyclic Cloud): https://new-nbme.cyclic.cloud/question-images/A%2043-year-old%20man%20comes%20to%20the%20physician%20for%20a%20follow-up%20examination.%20Ten%20years%20ago%2C%20he%20underwent%20cardiac%20valve%20replacement.%20Chest%20x-rays%20are%20shown.%20Based%20on%20these%20findings%2C%20which%20of%20the%20following%20valves%20was%20most%20likely%20replaced%20in%20this%20patient%3F

Please help

Initially i was using the file system to store images but as cyclic does not support writing on file system and gives EROFS error, i tried saving the images on mongoDB and directly fetch them, i worked fine on local machine, but this is not working on cyclic.
Here is the client side code for fetching-

```
function displayCurrentQuestion() {
    const question = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
    const urlFriendlyQuestion = encodeURIComponent(question.question);

    const questionImage = question.image ? `<img src="/question-images/${urlFriendlyQuestion}" 
        alt="Question Image" />` : '';
    let checkboxesHtml = '';
    question.options.forEach((option, index) => {
        const isChecked = userResponses[currentQuestionIndex] &&            userResponses[currentQuestionIndex].includes(option);
        const alphabeticalIndex = String.fromCharCode(65 + index);

        checkboxesHtml += `
            <label style="font-weight:500;">
                <input id="checkbox-round" type="checkbox" name="option${index}" value="${option}"          ${isChecked ? 'checked' : ''}>
                <span ${isChecked ? 'checked' : ''}">${alphabeticalIndex}) ${option}</span>
         </label><br>
        `;
    });
    questionContainer.innerHTML = `
    ${questionImage}
        <p>${currentQuestionIndex+1}. ${question.question}</p>
        ${checkboxesHtml}
    `;
}
```

Here is the server side handling-

```
app.get('/question-images/:questionForImage', async (req, res) => {
  
  const imageQuestion = req.params.questionForImage;
  console.log("server side " + imageQuestion);
    try {
        // Retrieve the image from the database based on the question
        const reqImage = await Question.findOne({ question: imageQuestion });
        if (!reqImage) {
            return res.status(404).send('Image not found');
        }
       
        // Set the appropriate content type header
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', reqImage.mimeType);
        // Send the image buffer
        res.send(reqImage.image);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching image:', error);
        res.status(500).send('An error occurred while fetching the image');
    }

});
```

Sorry for such a long question, this is the first time i have deployed any application.